# Add value of textarea to already filled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a input which will be prefilled from the cms and from another textarea: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b53zep8/)

```
jQuery('#description_field').on('change', function () {
   var val=jQuery("#description").val();
   jQuery("#description").val(val + ' ' +jQuery( "#description_field" ).val());
});
```

-

```
<form>
   <textarea id="description_field" name="description_field"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="{{ cms.tag }} <!-- Text of the textarea -->">
</form>
```

This is actually already working but when the user wants to alter the text in the `textarea` a second time, the changes are added at the end of the old `input` text which is not nice.

How do I have to change the code in a way, that the text is always 1:1 with the `textarea`?

Thank you

Comment: Why do so many people write `jQuery` instead of just `$` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille what is wrong with writing `jQuery`?

Comment: It's longer. I'm lazy. What if jQuery was named dieMeistenAwesomeJSBibliothekDerWelt ?

Comment: It comes in handy if you have multiple libraries implemented in the same project where `$` can be a shorthand for other stuff too.

Answer (score 1):

You can change:

```
var val=jQuery("#description").val();
```

to:

```
var val = jQuery("#description").attr('value');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8b53zep8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Store the field value before attach "change" event:

```
var val=jQuery("#description").val();
jQuery('#description_field').on('change', function () {
   jQuery("#description").val(val + ' ' +jQuery( "#description_field" ).val());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8b53zep8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```js
//store the initial value from input
var initialValue = $("#description").val();

$('#description_field').on('input', function () {
    $("#description").val(initialValue + ' ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="charge-form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description_field" name="description_field"></textarea>
    <hr>
    <input id="description" name="description" value="XYZ ">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want 1:1 text as you say, why not just : (run it below)

```js
var $textarea = $('#description_field'),
    $input = $("#description");

$textarea.on('keyup', function () {
 $input.val($textarea.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="charge-form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description_field" name="description_field"></textarea>
    <hr>
      <input id="description" name="description" value="XYZ ">
</form>
```